# Hard time figuring out the correct regex to match uppercase words

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, match

I have a simple requirement. We use the hibernate validation engine to figure out if a constraint is true or false.

True should be a text if all the words starts with an uppercase character.
There are some difficulties:

Words could also start like this

```
8-Test
or even
8Test
or even
(Test)
or even
-Test
or anything comparable
```

Also usually they are comma separated (or a different separator):

```
Test, Test, Test
```

**Remember I only want to make sure that words in the String starts uppercase. When you see my tries, probably I am overcomplicating things.**

Here are some samples:
Expected to match all (true):

```
- Hydroxyisohexyl 3-Cyclohexene Carboxaldehyde, Benzyl
- Test, Test, Test
- CI 15510, Methylchloroisothiazolinone, Disodium EDTA
- N/A
- NA
```

Expected to not match all (false):

```
- hydroxyisohexyl 3-Cyclohexene Carboxaldehyde, Benzyl
- Test, test, Test
- CI 15510, Methylchloroisothiazolinone, Disodium eDTA
- na
- n/a
```

My tries were going into this directions:

```
final String oldregex = "([\\W]*\\b[A-Z\\d]\\w+\\b[\\W]*)+";
final String regex = "([A-Z][\\d\\w]+( [A-Z][-\\d\\w]+)*, )*[A-Z][-\\d\\w]+( [A-Z][-\\d\\w]+)*\\.";'
```

actually with "**oldregex**" option I ran into an infinitive calculation for some texts
Use this to test regex: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ (without double backslashes of course)

Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Regex

See it **[in action](http://regexr.com?320ok)**:

```
^(?:[^A-Za-z]*[A-Z][^\s,]*)*[^A-Za-z]*$
```

### Explanation

```sh
^                # start of the string
(?:              # this group matches a "word", don't capture the group
  [^A-Za-z]*     # skip any non-alphabet characters at start of the word
  [A-Z]          # force an uppercase letter as a first letter
  [^\s,]*        # match anything but word separators (\s and ,) after 1th letter
)*               # the whole line consists of such "words"
[^A-Za-z]*       # skip any non-alphabet characters at the end of the string
$                # end of the string
```

**Note:** You can modify the regex if your word separator characters different then whitespace and comma. (For example, change `[^\s,]` to `[^,:-]` or whatever you use)

Comment: `[^\s,]` is incorrect since it would allow additional uppercase letters after the first.

Comment: Well, if I understood OP correctly, no such constraint needed! First letter must be an uppercase, others may be anything.

Comment: yep second characters can be upper case as well.

Comment: Same problem here: it runs into an infinitive calculation for specific text. E.g. can you test it like this:`String regex = "^([^A-Za-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)+.?$"; //true expected string = "AQUA, CETEARYL ALCOHOL, CETYL ESTERS, BEHENTRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, CETRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, AMODIMETHICONE, TRIDECETH-12, PARFUM, METHYLPARABEN, HEXYL CINNAMAL, LINALOOL, BENZYL SALICYLATE, LIMONENE, LAMINARIA DIGITATA, CHAMOMILLA RECUTITA , ANICOZANTHOS FLAVIDUS, SODIUM BENZ0ATE, PHENOXYETHANOL, ETHYLPARABEN, BUTYLPARABEN, PROPYLPARABEN, P0LYS0RBATE 20, CI 19140, CI 14700."; System.out.println(string.matches(regex));`

Comment: @user1635689 My regex [works fine](http://regexr.com?320m3) for this string also.

Comment: Maybe the WEB Regex page is handling the regex differently:  String regex = "^([^A-Za-z]*[A-Z][^\\s,]*)*$";
  //true expected
  String string = "AQUA, CETEARYL ALCOHOL, CETYL ESTERS, BEHENTRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, CETRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, AMODIMETHICONE, TRIDECETH-12, PARFUM,  METHYLPARABEN, HEXYL CINNAMAL, LINALOOL, BENZYL SALICYLATE, LIMONENE,  LAMINARIA DIGITATA, CHAMOMILLA RECUTITA , ANICOZANTHOS FLAVIDUS, SODIUM BENZ0ATE, PHENOXYETHANOL, ETHYLPARABEN, BUTYLPARABEN, PROPYLPARABEN, P0LYS0RBATE 20,  CI 19140, CI 14700.";

  System.out.println(string.matches(regex));

Comment: What is the cause? Is it explainable to a non pro? What about risks to see that again for other text? BTW. did what is the updated regex?

Comment: @user1635689 Fortunately, it is explainable :) Problem is at the end of the string. After skipping non-alphabet chars for a "word" match, if remaining items is not a valid word (starting with an uppercase letter) it was returning false. But, it should return true, because remaining characters neither uppercase nor lowercase. So, I made the inner group optional and problem solved (I think so for now).

Comment: seems like now he is running into infinitive calculation for `Acetamide MEA, Glycerin, Sodium Lauriminodiproponiate, Sorbitol, Hydroxylated Lecithin, Carthamus Tinctorius Seed Oil, Helianthus Annuus Seed Oil, Simmondsia Chinensis Seed Oil, Aloe Barbadensis leaf Juice, Simethicone, Avena Sativa Kernel Flour, Yeast Extract CI 15985, Melissa Officinalis Leaf Extract, Humulus Lupulus Extract, Foeniculum Vulgare Seed Extract, Cyclopentasiloxane, Cyclotetrasiloxane, Cyclohexasiloxane, Methylparaben, Propylparaben, Ethylparaben, Diazolidinyl Urea.`

Comment: what is the issue here :(??  The text doesn't look that weird so far

Comment: RegexBuddy reporting [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). I am looking for a solution.

Comment: @user1635689 I changed the regex again to avoid catastrophic backtracking. Can you try again?

Comment: Yep so far it does what I really want! Not sure though if I should be happy or scared to run into infinitive hangs again :) Do you have something to cal my fears? ;)

Comment: It was really hard time figuring out the correct regex :) Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Seems that one of the available texts I use for this regex is still causing this :( Just tested it, will need to investigate what was the text this time. Is there a way to make the regex more bullet proove & save?

Comment: Regex seems safe against catastrophic backtracking now. For finding other issues (if any), using a regex tool like RegexBuddy may help. No silver bullet AFAIK. I can help for any other cases.

Comment: That does the job right.... Thanks for the effort! `"^((^|[^A-Za-z]+)[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*[^A-Za-z]*$"`

Answer (score 1):

Tested this

```
^([^A-Za-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)+?$
```

It works on your test case

EDIT:

```
^([^A-Za-z]*?[A-Z][A-Za-z]*?)+.?
```

for performance issues

Comment: If you are going to match to end of string anyway, why use stingy matching?

Comment: Force of habit for using often dots to also match newlines (/m). Would this be an error anyway?

Comment: Hey thanks a million! Just one question. I have cases where the text ends with a "." or what evener character. I have changed yhe regex to "^([^A-Za-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)+.?$". Do you think that can have negative impacts? So far my tests looks good :)

Comment: Dot can match any character, if this is your intended behaviour ok, otherwise if you want to match only dots escape it like `\.?`

Comment: Help: with your regex I run into an infinitive loop as well for "AQUA, CETEARYL ALCOHOL, CETYL ESTERS, BEHENTRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, CETRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, AMODIMETHICONE, TRIDECETH-12, PARFUM, DMDM HYDANTOIN, METHYLPARABEN, HEXYL CINNAMAL, LINALOOL, BENZYL SALICYLATE, LIMONENE, PROPYLENE GLYCOL, CARICA PAPAYA, LAMINARIA DIGITATA, CHAMOMILLA RECUTITA , ANICOZANTHOS FLAVIDUS, SODIUM BENZ0ATE, PHENOXYETHANOL, ETHYLPARABEN, BUTYLPARABEN, PROPYLPARABEN, P0LYS0RBATE 20,  CI 19140, CI 14700.", WHY??

Comment: got it with this: ^([^A-Za-z]*[A-Z\d][A-Za-z\d]*)+.?$ can this infinitive calculation comeback for other cases? That's really critical :(

Comment: I am testing, seems such a strange behaviour! In my tests it works *after a while* however...

Comment: Ran into it again :( That is too unsave!

Comment: can you test it like this: <code>String regex = "^([^A-Za-z]*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)+.?$";
  //true expected
  string = "AQUA, CETEARYL ALCOHOL, CETYL ESTERS, BEHENTRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, CETRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, AMODIMETHICONE, TRIDECETH-12, PARFUM,  METHYLPARABEN, HEXYL CINNAMAL, LINALOOL, BENZYL SALICYLATE, LIMONENE,  LAMINARIA DIGITATA, CHAMOMILLA RECUTITA , ANICOZANTHOS FLAVIDUS, SODIUM BENZ0ATE, PHENOXYETHANOL, ETHYLPARABEN, BUTYLPARABEN, PROPYLPARABEN, P0LYS0RBATE 20,  CI 19140, CI 14700.";

  System.out.println(string.matches(regex));</code>

Comment: IS there a way to make it simpler? Basically every single word should start with an upper case character the rest is whitelisted.

Comment: Both regex have invalid cases: [first](http://regexr.com?320m0), [second](http://regexr.com?320lt)

Comment: This is infinitively calculating.... No end in Java :( String regex = "^([^A-Za-z]*?[A-Z][A-Za-z]*?)+.?";
  String string = "AQUA, CETEARYL ALCOHOL, CETYL ESTERS, BEHENTRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, CETRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, AMODIMETHICONE, TRIDECETH-12, PARFUM,  METHYLPARABEN, HEXYL CINNAMAL, LINALOOL, BENZYL SALICYLATE, LIMONENE,  LAMINARIA DIGITATA, CHAMOMILLA RECUTITA , ANICOZANTHOS FLAVIDUS, SODIUM BENZ0ATE, PHENOXYETHANOL, ETHYLPARABEN, BUTYLPARABEN, PROPYLPARABEN, P0LYS0RBATE 20,  CI 19140, CI 14700.";
  System.out.println(string.matches(regex));

Answer (score 1):

This is what I wanted: [Uppercase Words & Characters java matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215025/uppercase-words-characters-java-matches/12215990#12215990)

`"^((^|[^A-Za-z]+)[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*[^A-Za-z]*$"`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems right:

```
\b[^a-zA-Z,\s]*?[A-Z][^,\s]*?(\b|,)
```

The `\b`s match the word boundaries. The `[^a-zA-Z]*?` allows prefixes that aren't letters. Then we have our single uppercase letter with `[A-Z]`, followed by anything that's not an uppercase letter with `[^A-Z,\s]*?`.

Comment: returns false for  String regex = "\\b[^a-zA-Z,\\s]*?[A-Z][^,\\s]*?(\\b|,)";
  String string = "AQUA, CETEARYL ALCOHOL, CETYL ESTERS, BEHENTRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, CETRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, AMODIMETHICONE, TRIDECETH-12, PARFUM,  METHYLPARABEN, HEXYL CINNAMAL, LINALOOL, BENZYL SALICYLATE, LIMONENE,  LAMINARIA DIGITATA, CHAMOMILLA RECUTITA , ANICOZANTHOS FLAVIDUS, SODIUM BENZ0ATE, PHENOXYETHANOL, ETHYLPARABEN, BUTYLPARABEN, PROPYLPARABEN, P0LYS0RBATE 20,  CI 19140, CI 14700.";
  System.out.println(string.matches(regex));