# Uppercase Words & Characters java matches

Tags: java, regex

I can't get a simple regex to work, right now I have the following java code

```
String regex = "^([^A-Za-z]*?[A-Z][A-Za-z]*?)+.?";
String string = "AQUA, CETEARYL ALCOHOL, CETYL ESTERS, BEHENTRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, CETRIMONIUM CHLORIDE, AMODIMETHICONE, TRIDECETH-12, PARFUM, METHYLPARABEN, HEXYL CINNAMAL, LINALOOL, BENZYL SALICYLATE, LIMONENE, LAMINARIA DIGITATA, CHAMOMILLA RECUTITA , ANICOZANTHOS FLAVIDUS, SODIUM BENZ0ATE, PHENOXYETHANOL, ETHYLPARABEN, BUTYLPARABEN, PROPYLPARABEN, P0LYS0RBATE 20, CI 19140, CI 14700.";
System.out.println(string.matches(regex));
```

The problem is that the execution never ends. 
Please use my regex only to see how I fail. What I need sounds simple to me:
 - There can be any text.
 - All words in this text should be upper case. 
 - If there are Single characters, they should be uppercase too. 
 - Anything between (numbers, comma,...) should be matched always. 
See complex sample above.
Simple is:

```
Test, Test, Test = true
Test, test, Test = false
Test, 7-Test Test, Test = true
Test, 7-Test test, Test = false
na = false
NA = true
N/A = true
PHENOXYETHANOL, P0LYS0RBATE 20, CI 19140, CI 14700. = true
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I dont understand this one : Test, 7-Test test, Test = false . It has comma it should be true no?

Comment: There is a word `Test [test]` that is not in upper case.

Comment: Have you considered using the approach described in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194456/regular-expression-hangs-java-matcher)

Comment: nope test is lowercase, So simply: allow everything as long as words  starts upper case or a single character is upper case

Comment: @Edd yes tried every approach, either I run into infinitive caluclation time or the regex does not match uppercase words or gets confused by "." or numbers.

Comment: @Jocelyn Despite the commas, the OP seems to want the words seperated by spaces - the commas presumably should be grouped with the the preceding word. I presume something like `Test ,test` should pass if `Test, 7-test` also passes.

Comment: If you just want to know if the phrase satisfies your criteria, you just need to find if the string contains any lowercase letter that is preceded by a space or comma (starting of a word). i.e: `"Test, test, Test".matches(".*[, ][a-z].*") // true` and `"Test, Test, Test".matches(".*[, ][a-z].*") // false`

Comment: @Edd correct. `Test, 7-test` should fail. Also `Test ,test` should fail.

Comment: @Alex what if the first word is lowercase? Can I invert this regex? Because I use hibernate validation engine so I can inject my regex but no custom code.

Comment: @Alex consider this sample should fail `test, Test, Test`

Comment: You know that `.` matches *any character* in a regex right? You should use `\\.` or `[.]` if you want to actually match the period at the end of your line.

Comment: @DaoWen sure, I can know the `.`. Even though not sure what you want to point out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work on all the inputs you provided:

```
"^((^|[^A-Za-z]+)[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*[^A-Za-z]*$"
```

I'm not sure how your validator works, but it doesn't hurt to force matching the full string by adding the `^` and `$` symbols on either end.

Your regular expression never terminates because you used too many `*` (match zero or more) groups, which made the state space explode. Notice how I use a `+` on the `[^A-Za-z]` group, which forces it to match at least one non-letter between match groups. This keeps the number of matches to a reasonable number. However, since mine matches a full string (it starts with `^` and ends with `$`) it can only find a single match anyway.

***Edit:***

If you don't want the empty string to match then change the second-to-last `*` to a `+`:

```
"^((^|[^A-Za-z]+)[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)+[^A-Za-z]*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

you better use delimiter, for eg with a stringtokenizer and then check, it will be a lot more easier. use ',' as a delimeter and then trim each token and check with regex.

Comment: I use a validation engine. No chance to add java code. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you

String regex = "^([A-Z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9,./\-]*\s*)+$";

you may need to add some more separators (,./ and - in the example)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this regex works for you:

```
\p{Upper}*[^\p{Lower}]*\p{Upper}*
```

it means:

\p{Upper} any uppercase character

[^\p{Lower}] any character except lowercase ones

obs: a empty text will matches too

Comment: Why does it return false for `Test, Test, Test`?? beside that I like it